# LocalDB in visual studio installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012-localdb

I installed windows server 2008 R2 then subsequently installed visual studio 2015 and SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB. I copied my solution over from a different box to the newly installed box and opened it. I have an .sql file within the solution but when i click on the .sql file to open in vs and run against the localdb i get thje following error:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

I read that i need to install  need to install the sql server management objects. I tried this and it said Sql Native Client is not installed. 
Am i going down the wrong path. Do i need to install sql server 2012 express for localdb to work? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Installing SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2013 did the trick.